# Matter.js: placing text or images on the canvas behind objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, physics-engine, matter.js

I'm wanting to place font or static images onto the canvas but not sure what the best approach is using Matter.js.  Right now, for images, i'm just creating a body with a size of '0' and putting the image url in the render.sprite.texture property.  Seems to do the trick but is there a different/better way of putting static images on the canvas?

Also, I am putting text onto the canvas using the 'afterRender' event near the top of my scripts, before anything else is created/drawn:

```
_sceneEvents.push(
    Events.on(_engine, 'afterRender', function(event) {
        var context = _engine.render.context;
        context.font = "45px 'Cabin Sketch'";
        context.fillText("THROW OBJECT HERE", 150, 80);
    });
);
```

Only problem is the text keeps getting drawn on top so my draggable objects keep going behind the text.  I just want the text to stay in the background, like a static image, but I figured drawing the font onto the canvas might be better than having to make the user download another image.  Any help?

Comment: Is the canvas just a way to get text onto the body? If so, you might be pushing the prototype render beyond its intent and using the DOM as your renderer might be a better approach. See [Matter.js Text inside a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72849141/6243352)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The renderer included with Matter.js is really only intended for demonstration, so the best thing to do is make a copy of the example [Render.js](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/src/render/Render.js) and then implement all of your rendering there (where `Render.world` is the entry method called on each tick).

Change the object name to something else like `CustomRenderer`, then pass your render class through in the `Engine.create` options:

```
var engine = Engine.create({
    render: {
        element: element,
        controller: CustomRenderer
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

A little late, but the documentation for this shows you had the correct method in adding the sprite to the renderer:

```
    let head = Bodies.circle(450, 50, 17, {
                render: {
                    sprite: {
                        texture: './img/head.png'
                    }
                }}
            );
```

https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/examples/sprites.js

(No idea about the text part of the question, yet)

Answer (score 2):

this is how you could return text string in a function as base image

```
createImage($string) {

    let drawing = document.createElement("canvas");

    drawing.width = '150'
    drawing.height = '150'

    let ctx = drawing.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(75, 75, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.font = "20pt sans-serif";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText($string, 75, 85);
    // ctx.strokeText("Canvas Rocks!", 5, 130);

    return drawing.toDataURL("image/png");
},

// and then e.g. in your sprites

// ...

render: {
  sprite: {
      texture: createImage("Your Text String")
      xScale: 1,
      yScale: 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default renderer for Matter.js isn't really intended to be used this way. Most often, you want to use either a custom renderer (like [liabu talked about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26329512/2065702)) OR connect Matter to your DOM elements like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72849141/2065702) covers.